# Xamarin Editor line breaks using XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to add line breaks to a editor placeholder in Xamarin with XAML. Unfortunately I cant use \n or < br/> for new lines.

Does anyone have a idea how to work around this behavior?

I tried this and it wont work:

```
<Editor Placeholder="This is one line \n this is the next one."/>
```

Expected result:

> This is one line 
>  this is the next one.

My result:

> This is one line \n this is the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `&#x0a;`, i.e.:

`<Editor Placeholder="This is one line &#x0a; this is the next one."/>`

The `&#` notation is a XML encoding for special characters. See also this article [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

Comment: Now I have the problem, that the placeholder doesn't automatically wrap it contents if the screen is to small ... But nice hint!